# Why does $p(Z=z | X=x) = p(Y=z-x | X=x)$ if Z=X+Y?

Tags: probability

I was working on a probability problem where was three random variables $X , Y , Z$ as follows :

$X=\{x_1 ... x_r\}$

$Y=\{y_1 ... x_s\}$

$Z=X+Y$

there was a claim that because of $Z=X+Y$ then $p(Z=z | X=x) = p(Y=z-x | X=x)$. I want to know why is this true??

Comment: Just use the fact that $Y=Z-X$ whence $Z=z$ from probability variable and $X=x$ from the conditional variable.

Comment: I can't imagine any example for it.Can You post any example? (it's kind of confusing)

Comment: This might help: http://www.statisticalengineering.com/sums_of_random_variables.htm.   good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, you may think about it this way:

We have three things we can fix: $X, Y$ or $X+Y$. Notice that if we fix two of them, the other one is determined, because we can solve for it. For example, if I tell you that X = 3, and X+Y = 5, you'll tell me I'm a liar if I claim $Y=1$, because you know $Y$ has to be $2$.

In particular, the probability that $x+y=z$ for a particular $z$ given that $x = x_0$ is *precisely* the probability that $y = z - x_0$ because if $y = z-x_0$ then $x_0 + y = z$ but otherwise $x_0 + y \not = z$. Hence, the event $y = z-x_0$ happens if and only if the event $x_0 + y = z$ happens. So, the probabilities that either of these events occur are equal.